# Finding required megapixels

Tags: megapixels, pixel-size

Is there anyway to find out how many megapixels would be required to get a level of detail on an object of a certain size? I'm wanting to clearly veiw lettering that is about 1ft*5ft that s on an object about 200ft long. The object would fill the frame.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you can derive your answer from https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/12434/26456

Answer (score 1):

This is not a mathematical aproach but an empiric one. Draw an example on a vector based program.

Figure 1 is a 24mpx representation of the object and text you describe. Download  to see them in real size.

The text is 5/200 of the total length of the image. It is the same as 1/40. So if a 24 Mpx has 6000px width this text will have 6000/40=150px.

[image]

Figure 2 is a 56Mpx.

[image]

The level of detail depends also on the font used, and the sharpness of the lens.